# how to update the content in the UIlabel

Tags: objective-c

When I use swipe gesture on the screen the label on the screen it didn't update the content and the number stop at 120, after I declare:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic)  UILabel *label;
```

when I swipe the screen then it appear error on the Xcode,

If someone can help me to solve this problem I will really appreciate it

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    double numOfSpeed;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic)  UILabel *label;

@end

implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    numOfSpeed = 120;
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 300, 100, 100)];
    label.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", numOfSpeed];
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor;
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeToControlTheSpeedOfRhythm:)];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeToControlTheSpeedOfRhythm:)];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeToControlTheSpeedOfRhythm:)];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeToControlTheSpeedOfRhythm:)];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [swipeUp setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];
    [swipeDown setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown];
    [swipeLeft setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [swipeRight setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [swipeUp setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [swipeDown setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
}

- (void)swipeToControlTheSpeedOfRhythm:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"gesture respone");
    if(sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
    {
        numOfSpeed -= 10;
        self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", numOfSpeed];
        NSLog(@"gesture Left respone");
    }else if (sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown){
        numOfSpeed -= 10;
        self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", numOfSpeed];
        NSLog(@"gesture down respone");
    }else if (sender.direction==UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp){
        numOfSpeed += 10;
        self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", numOfSpeed];
        NSLog(@"gesture up respone");
    }else if(sender.direction==UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight){
        numOfSpeed += 10;
        self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", numOfSpeed];
        NSLog(@"gesture right respone");
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: You're recreating `label`?

Comment: Please post the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should init your `UILabel` like this:

```
self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 300, 100, 100)];
```

Then use `self.label` through all your code. The problem is that your label property is not being assigned inside your `viewDidLoad` code.

**Edit**

And use a `strong` reference in your `UILabel` property unless you're using `@IBOutlet`s.

Comment: sorry, i had tried the code you suggested me, but it doesn't work
i set the property like this @property (strong, nonatomic)  UILabel *label;

Comment: then change all self.lab in my code, but i still can't pass compile

Comment: [self.view addSubview:label]; it appear " use of undeclared identifier 'label' "at this line , i am really sorry i know its a easy bug but i am beginner so i can't figure it out. thank a lot

Comment: Try ``[self.view addSubview:self.label];``. You're missing the ``self`` statement to access the ``@property``.

Comment: i solve this problem after i use this code, "[self.view addSubview:_label];",
thanks a lot

Comment: @hungwei0331 keep in mind that with ``self.label`` you're accessing the property through the generated accessor and with ``_label`` you're directly accessing the instance. If you decide to access the instance directly, remember that you must init the property before.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "UILabel *" from

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 300, 100, 100)];
```

Comment: This is at least part of the problem, but the answer should explain itself.  You mean, set the property instead of a local, and use "self".

Comment: sorry, u mean the code like this one? *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 300, 100, 100)];